# I think that's rather after Phoebe

Tags: vocabulary

> “Jennifer, look. I feel so bad if Phoebe’s up here and you’re up into look at after her.”
>   “We don’t mind, huh. We don’t mind at all.”
>   “Thanks but she needs to be back at home with me, to where she belongs.”
>   “I think that’s rather **after Phoebe**. Don’t you?”
>   (The Archers, BBC radio 4, part of this is [here](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/475))

It seems that ‘after’ denotes ‘dependent upon,’ I guess. But I can’t find it in dictionaries. Is it so? Or is there an omission after the phrase, e.g. ‘after Phoebe (has her time here)’?
(Jennifer: Phoebe's grandmother (Phoebe's mother's side), the other speaker is Phoebe's father))

Comment: I heard that line as "Well, I think that's rather up to Phoebe. Don't you?"

Comment: Yes, it's **up to** (Phoebe) .

Comment: 'After' as in 'behind, or trailing'. So the decision follows Phoebe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialog is actually:

> "Jennifer, look, I feel so bad that Phoebe's up here and you're having to look after her."
>   "Oh, we don't mind, we don't mind at all."
>   "Thanks, but she needs to be back at home with me, where she belongs."
>   "Well, I think that's rather **up to** Phoebe, don't you?"

Meaning that the decision is Phoebe's to make, and no-one else's.